# Update Number of Tab in TabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have building app with Material Tab

I have list data from server, from this data i will define number of tab in my fragment. 
But I cannot know how to update them. The layout can not change.

In onCreateView():

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classroom, container, false);
    tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("abcd").setTabListener(this));
    }
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }
    });
    getData();
    return rootView;
```

getData():

```
String url = Constants.API_GET_ROOM_IN_FLOOR;

    sender.start(url, new RequestSender.IRequestSenderComplete() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestComplete(String result) {
            items = ParseUtils.parseClassInfo(result);
            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), items);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            updateView();
        }
    });
```

I had get data from server, and now i will use updateView() function to update new number of tab in layout.

I dont know how to write this function in this fragment.

Please help me to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late answer.

To do this, we call function:

```
tabHost.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It will update number of tab